# Undefined symbol: _vkCreateInstance

Tags: c++, xcode, graphics, 3d, vulkan

While compiling program shows error like this, even through Header Search Path has been configured in xcode (latest version).

Vulkan downloaded version - 1.2.177; GLFW and GLM are configured and working properly.

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_vkCreateInstance", referenced from: VulkenRenderer::createInstance() in VulkenRenderer.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: What's up with the underscore?

Comment: Did you tell the linker where to find the Vulkan library for your target platform and architecture?

Comment: Any news here? I'm very new to vulkan as well as C++ and have a very similar problem. Cant find a fix for it though...